# Jqplot yxes min value

Tags: string-formatting, jqplot, format-string

Whenever I am setting up the min value to 0 on the Y-axis my ticks are changing to decimal numbers. The above code displays numbers like 80, 90, 100 on the Y-axis:

```
 yaxis:{
     autoscale: true,
     formatString: "%d"
 }
```

When `min` option is set the ticks are displayed like 80.00, 90.00, 100.00.

```
yaxis:{
     autoscale: true,
     min: 0,
     formatString: "%d"
 }
```

How can I avoid changing the string format when adding the `min` option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding

```
tickInterval: x
```

For example:

```
yaxis:{
 autoscale: true,
 min: 0,
 formatString: "%d"
 tickInterval: 10
}
```